# How to customize the reading order by screen readers of a three-column layout?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I am working on developing a WordPress theme, and I am planning to develop it with Bootstrap. For this theme, there will be the option of having a three column (left sidebar, content, right sidebar) layout, (or even just a left sidebar then content would work for this question).

Anyway, I am blind, so am acutely aware of how annoying it would be to have to move through a sidebar on the left of the content with lots of widgets, just to get to the content itself, when a sighted user can just look down on the content. So my question: How can you make the screen reader (maybe the dom?) see the left sidebar as coming after the content, yet still have it be directly to the left of the content with Bootstrap?

I thought of a possible way, namely making two blank divs in columns 1 and 3 with the content between them, then going to a new row and doing columns 1 and 3 with a blank div between them, but this just seems really hackish.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARIA spec defines an [`aria-flowto` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-flowto); however, screen reader support for this property is limited. See the following web pages for more information:

- WCAG wiki article [Using aria-flowto](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-flowto)
- [Using `aria-flowto` to give users a choice of reading order](http://3needs.org/en/testing/code/aria-flowto.html)
- [ARIA-Flowto (property)](http://www.maxability.co.in/2014/09/aria-flowto-property/)

I just checked the example on the "[Using `aria-flowto` to give users a choice of reading order](http://3needs.org/en/testing/code/aria-flowto.html)" page in Safari 9.0.1 / VoiceOver for Mac OS 10.11.1 and Firefox 41.0.2 / Windows Narrator for Windows 10, and found that the `aria-flowto` had no effect. In Microsoft Edge browser / Windows Narrator, navigating from "The Daily Planet" skips to the election results section, then to the sports news section, but does not return to the weather section.  So, it appears that there is partial support for `aria-flowto` in that combination of browser and screen reader.

The typical way to customize the reading order is to make sure that the source order of content in the document matches the desired reading order.  Using Bootstrap, you can place the main content area first in the document, followed by the left sidebar content, and then by the right sidebar content.  You can use [Bootstrap's column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) CSS classes to visually swap the left sidebar and main content areas.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main-content" class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
            Main content.
        </div>
        <div id="left-content" class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
            Left sidebar content.
        </div>
        <div id="right-content" class="col-md-3">
            Right sidebar content.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the main content markup appears first in source order and is pushed over 3 columns (visually) via `col-md-push-3`.  The left sidebar markup appears next in source order and is pulled over 6 columns (visually) via `col-md-pull-6`.

Here is a live JSFiddle:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/pkywjac5/show/

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form" runat="server"   method="post">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="row col-md-4">LeftSidebar</div>
        <div class="row col-md-4">Content</div>
        <div class="row col-md-4">RightSidebar</div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're using a form here, and how the other pieces fit together -- I don't see how this would make the left sidebar appear to screen readers after the content, but I am new at this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp.You can refer about bootsrap forms here